# Error Sending NSData packet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am making an app which sends an integer to the other player. For now I just want it to make it send the packet upon startup. This VC only loads when the player has found a match.
Here is the code. It comes up with the error sending packet I made. Why won't it send?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.totalApples = 3;
    self.matchStarted = YES;
    int tempTotalApples = self.totalApples;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&tempTotalApples length:sizeof(tempTotalApples)];
    [self sendData:data];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)sendData:(NSData *)data {
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending init packet");
        [self matchEnded];
    }
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    int i = 0;
    [data getBytes:&i length:sizeof(i)];
    label.text = @"&f", self.totalApples;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Husyn NSLog(@"Error sending init packet");
As in it does not successfully send the packet as I have coded in that message

Comment: I'm asking about actual error message. Do something like NSLog(@"Error sending init packet. Error: %@",[error description]);

Comment: @Husyn (null) Does that help?

Comment: What is the data type of match object? And include a check if data is null or not.

Comment: The match object is a GKMatch? How would I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38667/discussion-between-husyn-and-sherrie-crane)